# Can I delete parent DNS zone of AD domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

We currently have a single AD domain internal.mycompany.com

There are currently 2 independent authoritative copies of the parent DNS zone mycompany.com. One copy is managed by the domain controller, the other by the external domain hosting company.

There are no DNS records within the mycompany.com zone that I need internally that couldn't just be resolved by querying the external DNS servers.

Can I safely delete the copy of the mycompany.com zone on the domain controller without affecting internal.mycompany.com and my Active Directory domain?

I had planned on pausing this zone for a week, just to make sure there was no impact, but it didn't then forward the queries on for this zone to the external DNS servers. I understand this is expected behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have DCs in mycompany.com? If not, that zone is not part of the AD forest and should not be affected.

Comment: Thanks @GregAskew. No, there are no domain controllers in the parent zone. I'll schedule the work and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As long as "mycompany.com" is not directly associated with an AD Forest, you can remove it without affecting Active Directory.

In order to test external functionality without pausing resolution of the zone you can update the "nameserver" records to point to the nameservers of your external DNS provider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).